# KnockOut JS - applying a new binding. Error - Message: ReferenceError: 'router' is undefined; Bindings value: css: { active: router.isNavigating }

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

In my application I have an event for adding a new nested object to my observable array. In my code I am trying to do this:

1. Change my observable array into a standard JS object. Lets call this objAgency.
2. Create a new object with properties. I will call this objContact.
3. I splice the old data from objAgency by using an ID that I have in the code.
4. I add objContact in its place.
5. I convert objAgency back into an observable.
6. I map objAgency to my bindings, but this gives me the below error:

   ```
   Unhandled exception at line 1936, column 17 in http://localhost:13762/scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js

   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.

   Message: ReferenceError: 'router' is undefined;

   Bindings value: css: { active: router.isNavigating }
   ```

This is my agency.js file

```
define(['services/datacontext'], function (dataContext) {
    var initialized = false;
    var agency;

    agency = ko.observableArray([]);
    brands = ko.observableArray([]);

    var vm = { // This is my view model, my functions are bound to it. 
        //These are wired up to my agency view
        activate: activate,
        agency: agency,
        brands: brands,
        title: 'agency',
        refresh: refresh, // call refresh function which calls get Agencies
        save: save,
        cacheForm: cacheForm,
        addOffice: addOffice,
        addBrand : addBrand,
        removeBrand: removeBrand,
        addContact: addContact,
        removeContact: removeContact
    };
    return vm;

    function activate() {
        vm.agency;
        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }
        initialized = false;
        refresh();
    }

    function refresh() {
        dataContext.getAgency(agency);
        dataContext.getBrands(brands);
    }

    function addBrand() {
        brands.unshift({
            brandName : ""
        });

        // Change td css to editable textbox
        jQuery("#tblBrand td:first input").removeAttr('readonly');
    }

    function removeBrand(brand) {
        brands.remove(brand);
    }
```

**This is my addContact function where my code breaks**

```
    function addContact(office) { // Passing in object array of agency. We no it contains correct office and agency ID

        // Convert agency to object
        objAgency = ko.toJS(agency);

        // Get ID of office I am changing
        var officeID = office.officeID._latestValue;

        // Convert from observable to vanilla object
        objOffice = ko.toJS(office);

        // Fill new object with empty strings and related data
        var contact = {
            agencyID: office.agencyID._latestValue,
            emailAddress: "",
            firstName: "",
            jobName: "",
            office: "",
            OfficeID: office.officeID._latestValue,
            personID: "",
            surName: "",
            title: ""
        }

        // Unshift new object to front of object. It will be first row in table.
        objOffice.contacts.unshift(contact);

        // Convert back into observable
        //obsOffice = ko.observableArray([ko.mapping.fromJS(objOffice)]);

        // Splice where office ID match
        for (i in objAgency[0].offices) {
                if (!isNaN(i)) {
                    if (objAgency[0].offices[i].officeID === officeID) {
                        objAgency[0].offices.splice(i, 1); // At i remove one object
                    }
                else {

                }
            } 
        }

        objAgency[0].offices.unshift(objOffice);

        agency = ko.observableArray([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency[0])]);

        vm.agency = agency;
        ko.applyBindings(objAgency);

    }

    function removeContact(contact) {
        for (i in agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue) {
            if (isNaN(i)) { // Escape if NaN, otherwise use index valI ha

            }
            else {
                for (ii in agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue[i].contacts._latestValue) {
                    agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue[i].contacts.remove(contact);
                }
            }
        }
    }          
});
```

I don't understand why **ko.applyBindings(objAgency);** does not work because the object hasn't changed apart from removing one nested object and adding a new one in it's place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you execute the problematic code, the Composition lifecycle of Durandal has bound the the `shell.js`and subsequently the ViewModel `agency.js` with the UI.

Meanwhile in the `addContact` function, at the last line you basically change the whole binding applied to the view:

```
ko.applyBindings(objAgency);
```

So your whole UI is now bound to this `objAgency` which I guess does not contain a router instance as the errors is pointing :

```
 ReferenceError: 'router' is undefined;
```

This error comes probably from the binding of the `shell` because is no longer bound to the UI since your code applied new bindings.

**SOLUTION:**

The `applyBindings` is managed by Durandal in the composition process. If you want to modify some properties of the ViewModel there's no need to update the bindings.

I don't know if the code you provided is working with your solution, however the `applyBindings` should not be there for sure.

To replace the data:

```
vm.agency([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency[0])]);
```

Or:

```
vm.agency.removeAll()
vm.agency.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. vm.agency in my code contains all the data that is being binded to my view. So I am trying to replace vm.agency in my function addContact. I am not sure how to do this?